# Hibernate update sometimes not done after ajax post

Tags: ajax, spring, hibernate, post

I have a button, which calls ajax POST method on a predefined URL. After the server has done its thing, it simply refreshes the page

The server fetches User object from the database and updates one column.

When the page refreshes then about 50% of the time, the User is still not updated and the refreshed page displays old information

Note - Code is cleaned up to only show the relevant

Ajax post method:

```
function buttonClick(){
   $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : "?open_class=1",
      success : refresh()
   });
}

function refresh(){
   window.location = contextPath;
}
```

Spring MVC

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/manager/listofquestions", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String listOfQuestionsPost(
        Model model,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        Principal principal) {

    if(request.getParameter("open_class") != null){
        userService.openClass(principal.getName());
    }
    return "success";
}
```

UserService

```
@Transactional
public void openClass(String name) {
    User user = userDao.getByName(name);
    user.setCodeword(codeWordService.GetNewCodeWord());
    userDao.update(user);
}
```

UserDao

```
public User update(User user) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(user);
    return user;
}

public User getByName(String userName) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where username=?");
    query.setString(0, userName);
    query.setCacheable(true);
    Object[] list = query.list().toArray();
    if(list.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return (User) list[0];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no uncaught exception on those 50% where your code fails? I fail to see any error handling on your code

Comment: I will look into this at the evening

Comment: No error happens. But i noticed an interesting thing - When the code is at openClass method. Then after "User user = userDao.getByName(name);", the ajax decides that the page post is done and reloads! Do you know why this is? The code keeps running fine after that call on the server side

Comment: Could be your code capturing exception and not doing anything somewhere, and as a result server returns success HTTP codes without anything

Comment: The funny thing is, that if i manually refresh the after the "false success", then it displays correct data. - I will try to add some exception handling there today

Comment: No, nothing. I put try catch blocks everywhere and i put breakpoint everywhere. I did notice a funny thing though. The debugger goes into the pages GET method - http://pastebin.com/je6UKPtE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that i failed to use Ajax correctly. The refresh method was called as soon as ajax post was started, thats why the page refreshed too fast. You need to do it like that:

```
success: function() { refresh(); }
```

Or use Jquery post like i ended up doing

To finalize it - problem wasnt with hibernate. But thank you for your support